# Linq distinct problem

Tags: linq

I am new to using LINQ, right now i have a query in sql with multiple inner joins and it works fine. I am trying to change this to a equivalent LINQ code, i could able to implement LINQ except for the Distinct fact i am using in my query...

my query

```
select DT.[Name], count(distinct([FeatureControlID])) as [Value], DT.[Weight]
from [DocumentTypes] DT inner join
[DocumentTypesSchema] DTS on
DT.[ID] = DTS.[DocumentTypeID] inner join
ProductsFeaturesControlsDocumentValues [PFCDV] on
DTS.[ID] = PFCDV.[SchemaID]
where [PFCDV].[ProductID] = 72
group by DT.[Name], DT.[Weight], [DT].[ID]
order by [DT].[ID]
```

and my LINQ without the Distinct condition is as below

```
 from dt in db.DocumentTypes
join dts in db.DocumentTypesSchemas on new { ID = dt.ID } equals new { ID = dts.DocumentTypeID }
join pfcdv in db.ProductsFeaturesControlsDocumentValues on new { ID = dts.ID } equals new { ID = pfcdv.SchemaID }
where
  pfcdv.ProductID == 72
group new {dt, pfcdv} by new {
  dt.Name,
  dt.Weight,
  dt.ID
} into g
orderby
  g.Key.ID
select new  {
  g.Key.Name,
  Value = (Int64?)g.Count(p => p.pfcdv.FeatureControlID != null),
  Weight = (System.Decimal?)g.Key.Weight
}
```

can anyone give me a hand on this? actually the linq code executes without the Distinct feature i used in the code.

Comment: what part of your query should return distinct results?

Comment: What is the `Distinct fact` in your query? Can you provide some details on that because I don't see distinct in your sql query either.

Comment: I have updated the mistake in my query, you can see distinct in sql now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
...
select new  {
  g.Key.Name,
  Value = (Int64?)g.Select(p => p.pfcdv.FeatureControlID)
                   .Where(id => id != null)
                   .Distinct().Count()
  Weight = (System.Decimal?)g.Key.Weight
}
```